# sfml does not compile anymore

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

I have the following basic code

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    sf::ContextSettings settings;
    settings.antialiasingLevel = 8;
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "PONG", sf::Style::Default,
                            settings);

    sf::Clock clock;

    sf::Time elapsedTime;

    srand(time(0));
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime();
        clock.restart();

        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();
        }

        // clear window
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        window.display();
    }
}
```

And when I try to compile it, I get the following errors

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sfml-astar.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x12c): undefined reference to `sf::WindowBase::isOpen() const'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x172): undefined reference to `sf::WindowBase::pollEvent(sf::Event&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/sfml-astar.dir/build.make:104: sfml-astar] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:96: CMakeFiles/sfml-astar.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:104: all] Error 2
```

My CmakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(sfml-astar LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(sfml-astar main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(sfml-astar sfml-graphics sfml-system sfml-window)
```

This code compiled *fine* just 12 hours ago. I reinstalled SFML once but it does not solve the problem. I am running arch linux.

Comment: How does CMake know what sfml is if you haven't added something like `find_package(SFML 2.5 COMPONENTS system window graphics REQUIRED)`?

Comment: I installed sfml system wide using pacman

Comment: You'd better use version control tools like git to track your code's change, I think you have changed the cmake config files.

Comment: the problem is: I did not change the code. I am starting a new project and copied the code from an old one (which compiled successfully yesterday). This project also does not compile successfully anymore

Comment: Run `make VERBOSE=1` and check the output lines for linkage.

Comment: FWIW, have you followed the [SFML CMake tutorial](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/compile-with-cmake.php) and does it fix your issue?

Comment: @alterigel ok, I added the dependency in cmake and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding the following to `CMakeLists.txt` (thanks @alterigel)

```
find_package(SFML 2.5 COMPONENTS system window graphics REQUIRED)
```